# How can write rewrite rule for my web application's url rewriting

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

i have My url like 
MyTravel/Tour/Inner.aspx?Pid=2&Cid=8 Goa/New-Goa/)

Here Pid and cid are coming from home page's menu which can be different according to menu selection.(My menu is created from database)

and some links generate url like 
 MyTravel/Tour/displaypackage.aspx?Pid=32&Cid=18&deptf=ND

i rewrite it as MyTravel/Tour/Goa/new-goa/ 
here goa and new-goa are saved in my database table on the basis of pid and cid.

I have used urlrewriter.net(Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter) for Url rewritting

Please tell me how I write my rewrite rule to match these type of urls in my configuration file.

Comment: Dear sir @ Paul Zahra  can you please give me a code....... thanks a lot

Comment: Please post the rewrite rule you use, surely it's just a simple change, i.e. &amp;deptf=([A-z]+)

Comment: Dear sir @ Paul Zahra I have 2 types of url when my inner.aspx is called with two querystring i have used
  <rule source="([inner]+)/[A-Za-z/\s-]*/[A-Za-z/\s-]*/" destination="HpContent/Inner.aspx?pid=$1&amp;cid=$2"/>
and when displaypackage.aspx called with 3 querystring then I have used
    <rule source="([display]+)/[A-Za-z/\s-]*/[A-Za-z/\s-]*/[A-Za-z/\s-]*/" destination=" HpContent /displaypackage.aspx?pid=$1&amp;cid=$2&amp;deptf=$3"/>
But when access my querystring in the page(.cs) it only gives inner as a param value of context(which I have used url rewriter)
Please help me!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think the () brackets you have around inner are confusing the issue so you have actually specified 4 parameters...

For:

```
MyTravel/Tour/displaypackage.aspx?Pid=32&Cid=18&deptf=ND
```

Try something like:

```
<rewrite url="~/MyTravel/Tour/displaypackage\.aspx\?Pid=([0-9]+)&amp;Cid=([0-9]+)&amp;deptf=([a-zA-Z]+)" to="~/MyTravel/Tour/$1/$2/$3" />
```

Comment: Your welcome ;)... now mark me as the answer and give me an upvote! :D